# Find your other account

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

So, I have 2 accounts here, this one (which I want to keep), and an old one with barely any reputation, that I don't remember the email to. Can I somehow find my other account by IP address, so I can delete it, or is there any other way?

Comment: A mod or CM should be able to find it by IP. But, fwiw, deleting your account is almost identical at the end of the day to never logging into it again (with the notable except of potentially identifying info you've left in your profile, of course), given that your content stays but you just end up disassociated from it. Not sure if that changes your thoughts at all.

Comment: @JasonC Well I'm question banned for questions I asked 4 years ago. Since then I've gotten 300+ rep

Comment: Do you know *anything* about your other account? Anything from the about me? A part of the display name? Anything keywords or anything in any posts you may have made? The web site from the profile? I [didn't find anything new with a search on "cristino"](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/675909) (aside from your current account), but maybe something else.

Comment: Or even the *site* this account has association with

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Stackoverflow

Comment: @JasonC I think I made this account throught the gmail button, but for the other I think I just typed in my gmail into the email box

Comment: This definitely sounds like a job for a mod, or even a CM. If you don't get a solution here on MSE try the "Contact Us" form down at the bottom of the page. But give it some time first.

Comment: @JasonC Ok I'll wait, then contact

Comment: @JasonC Mods can see IPs? Nice...

Answer (score 3):

There are tools available to a regular user that would let you do what you want - in fact, even with the appropriate mod tools, these things are usually logged when you access them - since they are personally identifying information or things that are not publicly accessible

With the amount of information we have, chances are ... its not worth bothering. If you don't know anything about the account, with the sheer quantity of new accounts here, it'll probably not even be noticed.

There's *mod* tools that let you search by username, email address or check for users with the same IP - however, you'd need to know/have been on the same IP, and those tools only work for sites where you have an account associated for the alternate.

And while a CM can search for you, *with* more information - abandoned accounts happen all the time and the best course of action, where there's almost no reputation involved, is to just leave it. It is just not a good use of their time.

So, my recommendation is to just let it be.

Comment: I'm question banned for questions I asked 4 years ago. Since then I've gotten 300+ rep

Comment: deleting an account won't really help with a qban.

Comment: I don't even get how I'm banned I got around -10 at max, and +300

Comment: +300 is not that much, And deleted posts count.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the email address you use for it, then chances are you're out of luck. We don't lookup past users that might be you based on IP, and certainly wouldn't delete it based only on that information. We pretty much require knowing the email associated with the account in order to do anything with it.

Comment: It also appears the OP should read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th and if they do remember the login for their other account - try to resist using it to ask any questions they currently can't.

Comment: I have the email

Comment: If you know the email then you can just use account recovery and log into it. But your question says you don't remember it. So which is it?